# Trying to Understand MVVM Better to stop doing code behind in Xamrian Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to learn to use my view models better in xarmain forms before in code behind I could just use a class and post that class to the method that saved to the database in mvvm how do I do the same here is my view model so far.

I am using fire base to deal as my data store But its the AddToInvoice invoice bit am stuck at normally in code behind I would code

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel()
vm.Description ="Test";
vm.Ammount = 39.99m;


someclass.AddToInvoice(VM);
```

I no have to use data biding such as this

```
 <Entry Padding="20, 10, 20, 10"
           Placeholder="{Binding Placeholder}"
           Text="{Binding Text}"
           BackgroundColor="#ffffff" />
```

But how do i do the same below

```
public  class InvoicesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    SimpleInvoiceFBClient sFbClient = new SimpleInvoiceFBClient();
    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceViewModel> Invoices { get; set; }

    public InvoiceHeader InvoiceHeaders { get; set; }

    public InvoicesViewModel()
    {
        Invoices = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceViewModel>();

    }
  
    public ICommand AddToInvoiceCommand => new Command<AddToInvoice>();

    public void AddToInvoice()
    {
       var result=sFbClient.AddToInvoice(invoiceHeader);


    }
    public void GetData()
    {

    }
}
```

My Simple View is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:material="clr-namespace:XF.Material.Forms.UI;assembly=XF.Material"
             x:Class="SimpleInvoice.Mobile.Views.AddInvoicePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <material:MaterialTextField x:Name="txtInvoiceNum"  Placeholder="Invoice Number" >                
            </material:MaterialTextField>

            <Button Text="Submit Invoice" Command="SubmitInvoiceCommand"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Must I really set additional getters and setters like this in my view model cant I just use the ones out of my invoice model below.

```
namespace SimpleInvoice.Models
{
    public class InvoiceHeader 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AddressTo { get; set; }
        public int AddressFrom { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

Also How does one pass an object like a class to a ICOMMAND

Comment: Potentially, you can have one `InvoiceHeader` property and bind the individual properties from that, as in `{Binding MyInvoiceHeader.InvoiceNumber}`.

Comment: I persume as long as that class inherits base view model so it gets notification changed events @RobertHarvey

Comment: I have two questions in one their also how do I pass say InvoiceHeader without needing to paramterise the AddToInvoice call it seems well messy

Comment: Can you please be clear in stating your problem and questions.

Comment: Its clear to others ! @AmjadS.

Answer (score 0):

> How does one pass an object like a class to a ICOMMAND

You could use `CommandParameter` , create the bind with the data you want to pass .

##### Sample

```
<Button Text="Submit Invoice" Command="{Binding AddToInvoiceCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding InvoiceHeaders }"></Button>
```

Comment: Will that pass the model as the binding sees it for the front end

Comment: In this way you need to set viewmodel as BindingContext in code behind .